# Wordpress after copy website don't work home page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I copyed website to my local machine and have some problems with redirection. I use OpenServer. At first time all link open domain name. What i did:

- Change `wp_options` siteurl and home to localdomain
- In `functions.php` wrote:

  ```
  update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://localdomain/' );
  update_option( 'home', 'http://localdomain/' );
  ```
- `.htaccess` contain only this:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  ```
- `wp-config` contain this:

  ```
  define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localdomain/' );
  define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localdomain/' );

  define('RELOCATE',true);
  ```

All link works fine exclude home page. I can't open local home, always redirect to domain name. Help poease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you copied site to your local machine you need run sql request for update urls:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'old_url', 'new_url') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'old_url', 'new_url');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'old_url', 'new_url');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'old_url', 'new_url');
```

It's should be done, because wordpress stored all urls in database.
Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check wp_option table details settings